# Why is this Yampa ball-bouncing going into an endless loop?

Tags: haskell, reactive-programming, frp

I'm trying to simulate a bouncing ball with the Yampa-Framework: Given an initial x-position, height and velocity, the ball should bounce according to gravity rules. The signal function takes a "Tip-Event" as input, the idea being "when the ball is tipped, it's speed should double".

The ball bounces nicely, but every time there is a tipping event, the function goes in to an endless loop. I figured I probably need to add a delay (dSwitch, pre, notYet?), but I do not know how. Any help would be appreciated!

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-} 

module Ball where

import FRP.Yampa

type Position  = Double
type Velocity  = Double
type Height    = Double

data Ball = Ball {
      height :: Height,
      width  :: Position,
      vel    :: Velocity
} deriving (Show)

type Tip = Event ()

fly :: Position -> (Height, Velocity) -> SF Tip (Ball, Event (Height,Velocity))
fly w0 (h0, v0) = proc tipEvent -> do
     let tip = (tipEvent == Event ())
     v <- (v0+) ^<< integral -< -10.0
     h <- (h0+) ^<< integral -< v 
     returnA -< (Ball h w0 v, 
                 if h < 0 then Event (0,(-v*0.6)) 
                  else if tip then Event (h, (v*2))
                   else NoEvent)

bounce w (h,v) = switch (fly w (h,v)) (bounce w)   

runBounce w (h,v)  = embed (bounce 10 (100.0, 10.0)) (deltaEncode 0.1 [NoEvent, NoEvent, NoEvent, Event (), NoEvent])
```

EDIT: I managed to avoid the endless loop by feeding back a flag when a tip occurred, but that still does not feel like the right way to do it...

```
fly :: Position -> (Height, Velocity, Bool) -> SF Tip (Ball, Event (Height,Velocity,Bool))
fly w0 (h0, v0, alreadyTipped) = proc tipEvent -> do
     let tip = tipEvent == Event () && (not alreadyTipped)
     v <- (v0+) ^<< integral -< -10.0
     h <- (h0+) ^<< integral -< v 
     returnA -< (Ball h w0 v, 
                 if h < 0 then Event (0,(-v*0.6), False) 
                  else if tip then Event (h, (v*2), True)
                   else NoEvent)

bounce w (h,v,alreadyTipped) = switch (fly w (h,v,alreadyTipped)) (bounce w)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few days hacking I think I found the answer. The trick is to use `notYet` to delay the switching event to the next point in time, so that the switching (and hence the recursive call to `fly`) occurs when the "old" tipping event is gone. The `second` function makes sure that only the second part of the result tuple `(Ball, Event (..))` will be put through `notYet`. This removes the endless loop, but also changes the semantics: The switching now takes place one "time step" later, this in turn leads to a different speed.

This Yampa thing is actually quite nice, sadly there is not much documentation to find. I still could not find out what the `pre` and `iPre` functions are good for, I figure they can be used in a similar context.

```
fly :: Position -> (Height, Velocity) -> SF Tip (Ball, Event (Height,Velocity))
fly w0 (h0, v0) = proc tipEvent -> do
     let tip = tipEvent == Event ()
     v <- (v0+) ^<< integral -< -10.0
     h <- (h0+) ^<< integral -< v 
     returnA -< (Ball h w0 v, 
                 if h < 0 then Event (0,-v*0.6) 
                  else if tip then Event (h, v*2)
                   else NoEvent)

bounce w (h,v) = switch (fly w (h,v) >>> second notYet) (bounce w)
```

Comment: iirc the are described in The Yampa Arcade paper.